# Explanation of a Solution to a Mathematical Induction problem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm quite stuck on the explanation that my university has provided for a tutorial question.

Here is the question with their working.

[image]

I'm just wondering how they got from line 6 to line 7.

Comment: Line 6 is $\frac12 \times (6(k^3+3k^2+3k+1)+3k^2+5k+2)$ ?

Comment: $(k+1)^3=k^3+3k^2+3k+1$, $(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1$, $3(k+1)^2=3k^2+6k+3$, $3k^2+5k+2=3k^2+6k+3-k-1=3(k+1)^2-k-1$

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: They got it by  starting from the end and then writing in reverse. It is the sort of unpleasant form of presentation where you know what you are aiming at so you always make the correct transformation to get you there. It is maybe suitable for the very formal final writeup but nobody "thinks" this way. The natural way how you would normally approach it when you are thinking about the problem and solving it yourself is to take the first and last expression, expand them and compare that they give the same. (And it would be completely correct to write it up that way, too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering line 6 is $$\sum_{i=1}^{k}(3i-1)^2 = \frac{1}{2} \cdot(6(k^3+3k^2+3k+1)+3k^2+5k+2) $$
We want to factorize this line in order to find which term could be factorized by  (k+1).
We know that $(a+b)^3 = a^3 + 3ba^2+3b^2a+b^3$ and that $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$.
The first step is to recognize $(k^3+3k^2+3k+1) = (k+1)^3$ and we're left with $3k^2+5k+2 = 3k^2 + 6k +3 - 1 -k = 3(k+1)^2 - (1+k)$.
You can rewrite it as $$\sum_{i=1}^{k}(3i-1)^2 = \frac{1}{2}\cdot(6(k+1)^3 + 3(k+1)^2 - (1+k))$$
and then factorize by $(k+1)$ which give you the answer you were looking for.